# Is it possible to let remote notifications show in the notification center even when an app is running?

Tags: ios, ios5, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to let a remote iOS5 notification show in the notification center even if my app is running, something like "I don't care about the remote notification at the moment even though I am running, let it show in the notification bar just as if I wasn't running"?

Comment: I want to do the same thing.  I've tried re-routing the request as a LocalNotification, but it does nothing (I just get my didReceiveLocalNotification immediately called).

Answer (score 0):

You show the UIAlertView to the user, instead of that.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
        NSLog(@"userInfo :%@",userInfo);

        NSString* msg = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];

        if (self._VCObj.isViewLoaded && self._VCObj.view.window) {
                // viewController is visible don't show.
        }
            else { // viewController is not visible
                [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
            }
        }
    }
```

[Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The only workaround I can think of is store notification somehow in app, and then on applicationWillTerminate(or some other method) schedule same notification as a LocalNotification and made it appear after second or two. This however could annoy me as a user if I get a notification right after I close some app :)